# Google places library gives blank page

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

When i have opened, page was blank. In place key i have copied my key but still it doesn't works. Someone knows what is wrong? I Have added html etc. I don't know why everytime when i open, page is blank. No errors or something.

```
<title>Place searches</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&libraries=places">

    var map;
    var service;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 15
        });

        var request = {
            location: pyrmont,
            radius: '500',
            type: ['restaurant']
        };

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style>

     #map {
         height: 100%;
     }

     html, body {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- you don't close `<script>` tag that loads Google Maps JavaScript API
- you include call for Maps JavaScript API twice
- you are missing the opening `<script>` tag in the code that initializes a map
- you use `initMap` as name of callback function, but in your code the name of function is `initialize`
- function `createMarker` is not defined

If I fix these issues map is loaded correctly. Have a look at fixed sample:

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pyrmont,
        zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
        location: pyrmont,
        radius: '500',
        type: ['restaurant']
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            //createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#map {
   height: 100%;
}

html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU" async defer></script>
```

You can also see the example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cutomaxoxi/edit?html,output

I hope this helps!